# Automate authentication of site which is using SAML

Tags: authentication, saml, saml-2.0

We have a website which we use to download our invoices from. We want to automate this process.
We do have username and password given to us to login to this website.
When I check network trace through developer toolbar, its clear that they are using SAML based authentication.

Questions is, can I automate this authentication just using Username/Password I have? or Does Identity provider has to allow this automated authentication from their side?
I could find their Identity providers URL, but passing Post request to IDP to get SAML response is not working (Was hoping to receive SAML assertion)

If IDP does not accepts only username, where does passwords come into picture? Does Service provider validates password before requesting assertion?

We are trying to find unattended ways to get these invoices.

Comment: The IdP authenticates the username/password then forwards the SAML Response via the browser to the SP AssertionConsumerService URL. The SP never sees anything other than the SAMLResponse from the IdP.

Comment: Right.  Is there way to send username/password through postman to receive SAML assertion response? seems IDP validates if request is from trusted SP? so we cannot send request from postman?